# Is it possible to set time zone in xulrunner with JS

Tags: javascript, xul

My app is based on XULRUNNER. I found when I fetch the current timestamp with Date.prototype.getTime, It seems give me the GMT time not the time of my time zone. But in firefox, there is no such a problem. I am confused that is there a way to set the time zone in xulrunner with JS.

Answer (score 1):

`Date.prototype.getTime` doesn't really have a notion of UTC or timezone, it's a number of milliseconds elapsed since a specific point in time, the Unix EPOCH, which happens to be defined in UTC. If you convert it to a date manually, you will always get a value seemingly in UTC, in XULRunner or Firefox.

You need to use the other methods on Date objects to retrieve the time in the local timezone.

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.getTime()); // 1390141979617
console.log(now.getUTCHours()); // 14
console.log(now.getHours()); // 9
```

Compare the results of `toString()` and `toLocaleString()`